# Proof by induction, is my proof incorrect?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Claim: $-1+2+5+8+...+(3n-4) = \frac{n}{2}(3-5n)$

Base:

$3(1)-4=-1$

$\frac{1}{2}(3-5(1))=-1\,\,$

Induction:

$-1+2+5+8+...+(3k-4)+(3(k+1)-4) = \frac{k+1}{2}(3-5(k+1))$

$\frac{k}{2}(3-5(k))+[(3(k+1)-4] = \frac{k+1}{2}(3-5(k+1))  $#by induction hypothesis

$\frac{3k-k5^2}{2}+\frac{6k-2}{2} = \frac{(k+1)(-5k-2)}{2}$

$-5k^2+9k-2 = -5k^2-7k-2$#false

Comment: Your claim is not correct. You should have written $$-1 + 2 +\cdots + (3n - 4) = \frac{n}{2}(3n - 5)\text{.}$$

Comment: @Antoine True, but if it's given claim, it's proof of incorrectness of thesis.

Comment: @Tacet It seems like an introductory exercise and his RHS is quite similar to "correct" RHS. These are the reasons that led me to the first comment.

Comment: The claim is stated as: $-1+2+5+8+...+(3n-4) = \frac{n}{2}(3-5n)$
and apparently it is true

Comment: @Antoine I assume it's first of task `Show that ... is incorrect` or I admit for instance typo in book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prove looks fine to me. I believe it would be easier to transform one side at a time, but it's just writing way.

You proved that implication has incorrect consequent for true antecedent, so your implication isn't fulfilled and you can't conclude on the basis of [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

If you had to prove for $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+)(\sum_{i=1}^n(3n-4) = \frac{n}{2}(3-5n))$ you can also show that it's incorrect for $n=2$ for example.

Comment: It must be a typo then, Thank you!

Comment: @Oliver You're welcome. You can also prove correct claim from Antoine comment. 
$$ (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+)(\sum_{i=1}^n(3n-4) = \frac{n}{2}(3n-5))$$
See that it's correct on [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SUM%28i%3D1+to+n%29%283i-4%29).

Comment: The equality holds for $n = 0$ as well:)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the book does not contain any typos in this excercise, your proof goes the right way, but it would be even better if you have added some comments in the induction step (and don't write down equations for which you don't know yet whether they hold or not):

We assume that the claim holds for $k$, i. e.
$$-1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + (3k - 4) = \frac{k}{2}(3 - 5k)$$
and **try to prove** that
$$-1+2+5+8+\cdots+(3k-4)+(3(k+1)-4) = \frac{k+1}{2}(3-5(k+1))\text{.}$$

By induction hypothesis, LHS can be simplified to
$$\frac{k}{2}(3 - 5k) + (3(k + 1) - 4)\text{,}$$
so we **have to check** if
$$\frac{k}{2}(3 - 5k) + (3(k + 1) - 4) = \frac{k+1}{2}(3 - 5(k+1))\text{.}$$

Then, simplify LHS and RHS separatly and find out that the claim is incorrect.